# add event.data for scrollLeft()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery `cont.scrollLeft(value)` which moves the scrollbar and triggers the scroll event, but I also need to add an event parameter so I would be able to identify in the event handler that this scroll was done by my code.

is it possible or maybe there's another way to do `scrollLeft(val)` and trigger the event so that I could add a flag that would be accessible from the `event` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any problems with this approach?

```js
var Scrool="user";

$("div.demo").scroll(function() {
  console.clear();
  if (Scrool==="code") {
  console.log("code scrolled")
  }else if (Scrool==="user"){
  console.log("user scrolled")
  }
  
});
$("#target").click(function() {
  $("div.demo").scrollLeft(300);
  Scrool="code";
});
```

```css
div.demo {
  background: #ccc none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 3px solid #666;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

p {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>scrollLeft demo</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="demo">
    <h1>lalala</h1>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>

  <button id="target">Click me</button>
</body>

</html>
```